# How to assign a number to array and display it in the listview?

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview

I have two activities. In first I put a list of items with a `ListView`. In the second, I want to put a list of items too, but the contents of which will depend on the position of the element, which was pressed in the first `Activitу`. Here is the code of the first `ListView` Activity:

```
public class ListView1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private ListView lv1;
    private String cats[];

//some code

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String category = bundle.getString("category");

        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
                    .createFromResource(this, R.array.first_list,
                            R.layout.list_items);
            lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
            cats = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.first_list);

        lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                String defStrID = new Integer(position).toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(ListView1.this, ListView2.class);

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("defStrID", defStrID);
                intent.putExtras(b);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the code which gets position of element in the list:

```
String defStrID = new Integer(position).toString();
```

I get it in the second `ListView` with:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String elementID = bundle.getString("defStrID");
```

and I have some arrays in `arrays.xml` for the second `ListView`. For example:

```
R.array.category1
R.array.category2
R.array.category3
R.array.category4
```

or arrays like this (it's not very important):

```
String category1[] = { //some items here }
String category2[] = { //some items here }
etc.
```

As an example, only a few arrays, actually more, so I do not want to use the `if else` construction. How to do it another way, I do not know. The second `ListView` activity will be the same as the first one, except for the described above.

---

Second activity:

```
public class List2 extends ListActivity {
    private ListView lv1;
    private String category1[] = {"Name1", "Name2"};
    private String category2[] = {"Surname1", "Surname2"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        ;
        String elementID = bundle.getString("defStrID");
        String arrayName = "category" + elementID;
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(arrayName, "array",
                this.getPackageName());
        Log.v("LOOK_FOR_ME", "category" + " and the id i got is " + id);
        String[] stats = getResources().getStringArray(id);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_items,
                stats));
    }
}
```

Comment: in second actitivy what you want array from xml>

Comment: @Samir Depending on the position of the element that was hit in the first activity, I want to put in the second activity appropriate array. For example: if I pressed first element in first activity, I will get listview with arrays from category1 in the second activity and etc.

Comment: the position you get in the first activity is Zero-based. values will be R.array.category0, R.array.category1, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second `Activity` get the id from the other activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String elementID = bundle.getString("defStrID");
```

If your arrays have the name `categoryX`(x -number) then build a String with the array name:

```
String arrayName = "category" + elementID;
```

Then you can get the id of that particular array like this:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(arrayName, "array", getPackageName());
```

and finally get the `String` array and put it in the adapter:

```
String[] stats = getResources().getStringArray(id);
```

Also keep in mind that the position in the list start at `0` so name your array starting with `0`;

Comment: I done that, but I got error: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x0`. I added the code that I've done in accordance with your answer to the question. Please, look.

Comment: @Sabre I tested the code and it worked. Try to clean the project and see if you really get the number from the first activity.

Comment: I tried to create a newclean project, but I've got NullPointerException. Can you give me your project, or, please, write full code of second activity.

Comment: @Sabre My code is like yours. I said to clean the project not create a new one: In `Eclipse` go to the menu `Project->Clean...` and then re run the app.

Comment: I've got the same error. It seems that I am doing everything as it should be, but it's not working(

Comment: @Sabre I don't know why it doesn't work. Put in your code some `Log.v` and see what you get for `arrayName` an the `id` you get from the method `getIdentifier()`.

Comment: I tried to get ID of clicked item in another simple activity with only textview. It seems that `defStrID` passes a correct number of element.

Comment: @Sabre Here is the Activity i used for testing http://pastebin.com/L90UtR4T , that works. `getIdentifier` returns 0 because it can't find your array.

Comment: So, I tested your Activity. It works, but you used only one array. When I've added some new as I described in question, I got `NullPointerException`. I added second activity that I used to the question. May be it's important: Eclipse says that `Strings category0, category1 etc aren't used`.

Comment: @Sabre That `NullPointerException` comes from another part of your code. For example in your first activity `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String category = bundle.getString("category");
` will throw a `NullPointerException` if you don't send a Bundle to the activity. Here is a small project i've created so you can see that my solution from my answer works : http://pastebin.com/Q3NUaGD0